# Whats the use of mysql.safe_mode in php.ini file?

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla

I've seen some website on security recommend to enable `mysql.safe_mode` in php.ini

```
# Enable SQL safe mode
sql.safe_mode = On
```

When I searched hard to find info on this, I found this:

> If the SQL Safe Mode option is enabled the MySQL and Ingres extensions
>   will ignore the supplied host, user and password information and will
>   use only the default ones.

By the sound of that, it really sounds like an unsafe mode than safe mode. Doesnt it mean, even if the application (say Joomla) supplies a mysql user with lesser previleges, enabling this will make mysql use the default root user for it? Have I misunderstood what it does? What is the benefit of enabling `sql.safe_mode` in php?

Comment: MySQL sets the default so if you only allow localhost to connect to a database regardless what is in php.ini the database can only be connected to with a local ip.

Comment: so what effect it could have to Joomla or wordpress installations if this is enabled? Is it safer to have it `on`?

Comment: If I am going to be connecting to database only as localhost from Joomla, I understand setting this to enable shouldnt have any effect isint it..

Comment: The default user doesn't have to be a highly-privileged one like `root`. If you use safe mode, you should set the default to a low-privilege user. Then if a script tries to use `root`, it will not be allowed.

Comment: So if I create a separate user and don't use the default root one to connect from cms applications, then setting mysql.safe_mode to on will not work since it may only use the default root one and not the new less privileged user supplied, is that right?

Comment: Just now I enabled `sql.safe_mode = On` in php.ini, created a less privileged sql user to install Joomla and it worked fine. So I guess sql.safe_mode will not prevent the sql users other than root from installing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use [safe_mode](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sql.safe-mode), set your database host, username and password in *php.ini* using the configuration parameters:

```
sql.safe_mode = On
mysqli.default_host = "127.0.0.1"
mysqli.default_port = "3306"
mysqli.default_user = "root"
mysqli.default_pw = "Password123"
```

By having it configured there you will not need it in your PHP scripts - enabling you to update your MySQL password from one place while also making your source code safe from including a password so that you don't have to keep manually removing the password prior to committing to source code version control repositories etc.

In your PHP scripts then instead of using:

```
<?php
$oDB = new mysqli( "127.0.0.1", "root", "Pass123", "database_name", "3306" );
```

You might use:

```
<?php
$oDB = new mysqli();
$oDB->select_db( "database_name" );
```

Comment: That's the first answer that made perfect sense. Thank you for answering with an example.

Comment: and is it good to set root access?